# Powershell parameterized string not seeing 2nd parameter placeholder

Tags: powershell

I'm defining a URL string in Powershell 2 function and writing it out afterward:

`$fullurl = [string]::Format("http://{0}/v1/users?login={1}",$SERVER_NAME,$USER_NAME)`

`write-host $fullurl`

...however, the end result seems to ignore the second parameter's placeholder.  Instead, I get output that reads `http://server user/v1/users/?login=`

When I test this in the powershell command line things work great.  Running as a script I see the result above.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. What is the value for `$USER_NAME`? Did you try a `write-host` on `$USER_NAME` to make sure it made it properly into the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this more directly in PowerShell by using string interpolation e.g.:

```
$fullurl = "http://${SERVER_NAME}/v1/users?login=${USER_NAME}"
```

BTW is your $SERVER_NAME variable actually set to `"server user"` as your sample output shows?  Could it be in your script that $SERVER_NAME is somehow getting assigned the values for both server name and user name?

If the above doesn't generate the expected url then inspect the values of the two variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Operator error in this instance, I called a function with those variables using comma separation and not spaces.